# Replace words in all wordpress posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a plugin to remove links from inside all posts in wordpress.
I wanted to upgrade the code, so that it would not only remove links, but also replace selected words. 
I auto import content, and sometimes it contain "bad words" and i was thinking i could replace these bad words with something more child friendly.
But my php is noob level, and i get really confused when i look at this code.

im thinking this should be a really easy fix, since i should be able to just copy part of the code, and in the copy select a target "bad" word and a replacement "good" word. But my skills have hit a wall.

```html
function remove_links_from_post($post){
    $post_content = stripslashes($post["post_content"]);
    if(!preg_match_all("/(<a.*>)(.*)(<\/a>)/ismU",$post_content,$outbound_links,PREG_SET_ORDER)){
        return $post;
    }

    foreach($outbound_links as $key => $value){
        preg_match("/href\s*=\s*[\'|\"]\s*(.*)\s*[\'|\"]/i",$value[1],$href);
        if((substr($href[1],0,7)!="http://" && substr($href[1],0,8)!="https://") || substr($href[1],0,strlen(get_bloginfo("url")))==get_bloginfo("url")){
            unset($outbound_links[$key]);
        }else{
            $post_content = str_replace($outbound_links[$key][0],$outbound_links[$key][2],$post_content);
        }
    }

    $post["post_content"] = addslashes($post_content);
    return $post;
}
add_filter("wp_insert_post_data", "remove_links_from_post");

?>
```

Comment: do you prefer plugin or just need a code?

Comment: code would be fine. I dont need a plugin.

Comment: So you need a word filter right?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this free tool to search/replace within Wordpress databases:
https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Since data is stored as serialized strings, it's more trouble to work with. This utility can search within these strings and do replacements without breaking the serialization.

I use it regularly with good success.

Comment: i do not want to search database and replace words, because then they need to be created on the website first, and i do not want that. So the solution dont work

Comment: I misunderstood your use-case. I thought you were doing manual replacements.

Answer (score 0):

you have to be careful to keep the string arrays consistent. A simple search and replace in the DB leads to unpredictable results.
Just have a look at the "Better Search and Replace"-Plugin: https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/

Comment: i understand, and i have tried the plugin you talk about. The problem is that i can only use this AFTER the post was created, and then it is to late. So the solution does not work.